# Выборка строк с одинаковыми значения

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```
select
  `id`, `name`, `sublink`
from
  cms_es_cats
where
  sublink LIKE 'products/ucenennye-tovary%'
```

Пробовал так:

```
select
  id, id_parent, name, sublink
from
  cms_es_cats
where
  sublink LIKE 'products/ucenennye-tovary%'
GROUP BY
  sublink
HAVING
  count(sublink)>1;
```

но выводит только 1 дублирующуюся строку, а мне также нужны и все её дубликаты

Как дополнить/дописать запрос, чтобы вывел строки только с одинаковыми значениями поля sublink ?

Comment: смотрите в сторону группировки по полю sublink и дальнейшего `having`

Comment: поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов, воспользоваться вложенным запросом, совместно с конструкцией `IN`

```
SELECT
  id, id_parent, name, sublink
FROM
  cms_es_cats
WHERE
  sublink IN (SELECT
          sublink
        FROM
          cms_es_cats
        WHERE 
          sublink LIKE 'products/ucenennye-tovary%'
        GROUP BY
          sublink
        HAVING
          count(sublink) > 1);
```