# Поиск совпадений в столбце таблицы БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ребят, подскажите, как правильно организовать поиск в одном конкретном столбце одинаковых значений ? При этом, эти значения заранее неизвестны. Может есть функция самого SQL ? 
По типу взяли первое значение - сравнили со всем столбцом, второе - сравнили со всем столбцом и т.д.
Боюсь просто, что есть в этом какая то загвоздка насчет потребляемых ресурсов )

Comment: Вот же https://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1062

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка строк с одинаковыми значения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561105/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)